# I am trying to validate that is end time is greater then small time with jquery

Tags: jquery

i am laravel developer and i have no experience with jquery but i am trying to validate that is end time is greater then start time but unfortunately i am little confused my jquery code right or not please help me thanks.

**eg.** start time = 09:14 and end time 12:15 - valid

and start time = 09:14 and end time 01:15 - not valid

thanks have a nice day

I think a/c to this time it should be validate.i am little confused why are giving me this error **end time should be greater then start time.**
[image]

**Html view**

```
             <div class="row my-4">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center mt-3">
                    <label for="" class="small text-muted">Select Time</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="time" class="form-control flatpickr"  name="start_time" 
                    id="start_time"  placeholder="Start Time" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <i class='bx bx-minus'></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="time"  class="form-control flatpickr" name="end_time" id="end_time" placeholder="End Time" >
                    <span class="endTimeMessage"></span>
                </div>
             </div>
```

jquery

```
    $(document).change(function(){
      var startTime =$('#start_time').val(); // 9:15 Am
      var endTime = $('#end_time').val();    // 1:00 pm

        var startTimeParts = startTime.split(":");
        var endTimeParts = endTime.split(":");

        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setHours(startTimeParts[0],startTimeParts[1],0,0);
        var endDate = new Date();
        endDate.setHours(endTimeParts[0],endTimeParts[1],0,0);
        if(endTime != ""){
          if (startDate < endDate){
            $(".endTimeMessage").hide();
            $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr("disabled",true);
            return true;
        }else{
            $(".endTimeMessage").show();
            $(".endTimeMessage").text("End time should be greater then start time");
            $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
            return false;
        }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I see you are using Flatpickr, you can try this feature.

The `totalWorkTime()` function checks if the work time is more than 0 seconds, but also not more than 24 hours.

When the start time is entered, the Flatpickr end time is updated to prevent users from entering a value lower than the start time.

For example, if a user enters the start time of 12:00 AM, they cannot enter 11:59 AM as the end time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const start_time = $('#start_time').flatpickr({
      enableTime: true,
      noCalendar: true,
      time_24hr: true,
      minuteIncrement: 30
  });
  const end_time = $('#end_time').flatpickr({
      enableTime: true,
      noCalendar: true,
      time_24hr: true,
      minuteIncrement: 30
  });

  $(document).change(function() {
    let your_msg = $('.endTimeMessage');
    let time_worked = totalWorkTime(start_time, end_time);
    
    if (time_worked != null) {
      your_msg.html(`You have worked ${time_worked} hours.`);
    } else if (isset(time_worked)) {
      your_msg.html(`End time should be greater then start time.`);
    } else {
      your_msg.html(`Notice: Not all fields are filled in.`);
    }

  });

  function totalWorkTime(set_time_start, set_time_end) {
    if (isset(start_time.selectedDates[0]) && isset(end_time.selectedDates[0])) {
      let date_start = set_time_start.selectedDates[0].getTime();
      let date_end = set_time_end.selectedDates[0].getTime();
      let max_date = new Date(date_start + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000);
      if (date_start > date_end) {
        // Update flatpickr to prevent value date_start to be higher then date_end
        set_time_end.set('defaultDate', max_date);
      }
      set_time_end.set('minDate', new Date(date_start))
      set_time_end.set('maxDate', max_date)
      let sec = Math.floor((date_end - (date_start)) / 1000);
      let min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
      let hours = Math.floor(min / 60);
      let days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
      hours = hours - (days * 24);
      min = min - (days * 24 * 60) - (hours * 60);
      return (isNaN(hours) || days !== 0 || sec === 0) ? null : ('0' + hours).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + min).slice(-2);
    }
  }

  function isset(data) {
    return typeof data !== 'undefined';
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.11/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 text-center my-3">
      <label for="" class="small text-muted">Select Time</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <input type="time" class="form-control flatpickr" name="start_time" id="start_time" placeholder="Start Time">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <i class='bx bx-minus'></i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
      <input type="time" class="form-control flatpickr" name="end_time" id="end_time" placeholder="End Time">
    </div>
    <div class="row my-4 text-center"><span class="endTimeMessage"></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir sir it's working perfect but i need to little change , i want to validate when the start time  is 10:00 and end time 10 :25 it should be not validate if i select start time 10 :00 and end time 10 : 30 it should be validate please help me how can i resolve thanku.

Comment: You only want to validate in steps of 30 min?

Comment: Yes sir minimum end time should be 30 min if we select 10:25 it should be error please select minimum 30 minutes .

Comment: For this you can use the Flatpickr function `minuteIncrement:` this will make sure the minutes goes up for example 30 minutes each time clicked. I have updated my answer.